# Angular drag and drop, exit event, get data of removed item

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-dragdrop

I'm trying to get value or index of the item removed from the source list using the "cdkDropListExited" event. I do see the event getting fired but the "event.item.data" keeps coming as "undefined".

How can I get the value or index of a list item as soon as it is moved from a drop container into another one.

Demo/Example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sy4bsr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is simply beause you're not assigning any data to you cdkDrag.

Take a look at the docs [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag) and look for `cdkDragData`.

So, in your code it would like this:

```
<div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item">{{item}}</div>
```